# Communication between two separate Dlls

Tags: c++, dll, ipc, windows-messages

I have a dll that is loaded by an application "A" and this dll export few functions. 
I have another application "B" that loads another Dll.
I want to call function of DLL A from DLL B.
Is there any way to achieve this via windows messages, ipc etc.

Comment: Why won't you load DLL A from DLL B as well?

Comment: @LiorKogan that would not be possible because dll A export one function which except specific parameter(Object Of particular type) which is available only from host application A

Comment: You may want to check out COM...

Comment: if process A and B belong to same user session and run at same integrity level, then Lior's suggestion makes sense.

Comment: What you seem to be talking about is inter-process communication. Is that right? You want to call a function in process A from process B (regardless of where that function is implemented, DLL or not)? Is that right?

Comment: You say (1) you want to call a function of DLL A (2) DLL A exports only one function (3) you can't call this function. I'm lost...

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz yes i am talking about ipc but i want to call function of Dll A via Dll B both are in septate in process

Comment: @LiorKogan Dll A export only one function. I want to call this function from Dll B. Both dlls are loaded into septate process.

Comment: There are various ways. One way is to use COM, another is sockets. You can use a windows message too, but that requires finding out the correct window handle to send the message. See here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/137/Sending-a-message-to-the-Main-Frame-Window-of-Anot

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz thanks